# Binding Enum with entity not working

Tags: wpf, mvvm, enums, datagrid

I have a table Called IGdaily with Field Trans_Category. I want to bind a DataGridComboBoxColumn displaying enum and binds its int value to datagrid cell Trans_Category.
My Enum

```
    public enum Enm_Purch_Ret : short
{
    Purchase = 1,
    Sale = 2,
    Return = 3
}
```

Viewmodel Vm_Purchase

```
public class Vm_Purchase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IGoldEntities db = new IGoldEntities();
    public ObservableCollection<IGdaily> Vm_IGdaily { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Enm_Purch_Ret> Vm_Enum_P_R { get; set; }
    public Vm_Purchase()
    {
        Vm_IGdaily = new ObservableCollection<IGdaily>(); 
        Vm_Enum_P_R = new ObservableCollection<Enm_Purch_Ret>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enm_Purch_Ret)).Cast<Enm_Purch_Ret>().ToList());
    }
     public ObservableCollection<IGdaily> IGDailys
    {
        get { return Vm_IGdaily; }
        set { Vm_IGdaily = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Enm_Purch_Ret> Enm_Purch_Rets
    {
        get { return Vm_Enum_P_R; }
        set { Vm_Enum_P_R = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In XAML

```
 <Window.DataContext>
    <local:Vm_Purchase/>
</Window.DataContext>
 <DataGrid x:Name="DG" ItemsSource="{Binding IGDailys}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding GroupName}" Header="Name" Width="200"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Item/Metal" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Trans_Category}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=Enm_Purch_Rets, StringFormat='\{0:D\}'}" DisplayMemberPath="Enm_Purch_Ret">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Enm_Purch_Rets, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Enm_Purch_Rets , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Trans_Category}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" FontSize="14" Header="Metal Id" Width="100"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>


  public partial class IGdaily
{
    public int GDaily_Id { get; set; }
    public int DailyMast_Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemGroup_Id { get; set; }
    public int Item_Id { get; set; }
    public int Trans_Category { get; set; }
}
```

Please help what is my mistake in binding. I am new to MVVM pattern.
please explain
Thanks

Comment: How is the IGdaily class defined? Please post it.

Comment: ok I have edited my code with  model IGdaily.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't set an `int` property to a `Enm_Purch_Ret` value because there is no implicit conversion between these two types.

But you could use a converter class that peforms the conversion for you:

```
public class EnumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Enm_Purch_Ret e = (Enm_Purch_Ret)value;
        return (int)e;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int i = (int)value;
        return (Enm_Purch_Ret)i;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG" ItemsSource="{Binding IGDailys}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:EnumConverter x:Key="conv" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding GroupName}" Header="Name" Width="200"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Item/Metal"
                                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Trans_Category, Converter={StaticResource conv}}">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Enm_Purch_Rets, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Enm_Purch_Rets , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Trans_Category}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" FontSize="14" Header="Metal Id" Width="100"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```